# angular reactive forms disable field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple reactive form and I'm using Angular material framework.

```
this.firstFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            builder_first_name: ['', Validators.required],
            builder_last_name: ['', Validators.required]
        });
```

And edit function that is saving this data.

```
handleEdit(event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.firstFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    if (!this.firstFormGroup.valid) {
        return;
    }
    this.mySerivce.update(this.firstFormGroup.value, this.project.id)
}
```

I want to make a `last_name` field readonly for some kind of users. But after I added simple logic:

```
builder_last_name: [{value: '', disabled: currentUser$.isAdmin ? false : true}, Validators.required]
```

I noticed that `this.firstFormGroup.valid` returns false right now.

I read this topic: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11432

But I still didn't find good solution how to handle all this. I tried `readonly` attribute, but how to deal with `<select>` and styles that applied to `mat-` fields that been disabled ?

Comment: If you see the docs about state: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status you see that a FormControl can be VALID,INVALID,PENDING **or** DISABLED. So you need ask about `control.invalid` (that's is status==INVALID) not about `!control.valid` (not valid can be status=INVALID or status==DISABLED). NOTE: remember that using your another aproach should be: `[attr.readonly]="currentUser$.isAdmin?true:null"`, see that is the condition  it's not sucesfully, the value is "null" -so Angular don't write the attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Eliseo.

When I changed condition to `this.firstFormGroup.invalid` everything is works as expected. I also changed `this.firstFormGroup.value` to `this.firstFormGroup.getRawValue()` to make sure that all field values is captured correctly.